# undefined is not a function (evaluating x.json())

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native

I'm using webview `onmessage` to get pass data from a webview to react native. The data that I'm passing is json and I'm passing it as plain text (this way I can parse the plain data on react native). When I try to parse the Json using `.json()`, I get this error:

```
undefined is not a function (evaluating x.json())
```

I don't know how or where I have to implement the json() function so I don't get this error. I'm using the following code.

```
  onMessage( event ) {
    Alert.alert(
      'On Message',
      event.nativeEvent.data.json(),
      [
        {text: 'OK'},
      ],
      { cancelable: true }
    )
  }
```

and

```
  <WebView
    ref={( webView ) => this.webView = webView}
    onMessage={this.onMessage}
    source={{uri: 'https://app.sodge.co/login/twitter?redirect=../response.html'}}
  />
```

The function is executed correctly without using .json() (but all I get this way is plain text as you can understand, because it's not parsed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript strings don't have `json` method. Use `JSON.parse` instead.
Another option would be to add `json` method on string;

```
String.prototype.json = function () {
    return JSON.parse(this);
};
```

**EDIT**:

For react-native you should prototype like this, and import this somewhere in the root of the app:

```
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, 'json', {
  value: function() { return JSON.parse(this); },
  enumerable: false
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings don't have a `.json()` method (like [`fetch` response bodies do](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json)). You will want to use

```
JSON.parse(event.nativeEvent.data)
```

Comment: All I get then is 'expected dynamic type string but had type object'

Comment: @QUIQUELHAPPY Are you using typescript?

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html#onmessage)

> window.postMessage accepts one argument, data, which will be available on the event object, event.nativeEvent.data. data must be a string.

Instead, you need to parse the JSON as

`JSON.parse(event.nativeData.data)`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the React Native docs explicitly state that `event.nativeEvent.data` must be a string:

> window.postMessage accepts one argument, data, which will be available on the event object, event.nativeEvent.data. data must be a string.

Since data is a string, use `JSON.parse` to convert it to a valid `JSON` object.